# Romberg's method in Python - creating function out of a list

Tags: python, numpy

I have an histogram `histo`, representing samples from a continuous function. I want to calculate the area underneath this curve. The histogram samples the function at positions corresponding to an array `x`.

First of all I use a trapezoidal rule:

```
dx = x[1:] - x[:-1]
result = np.sum(0.5 * (histo[1:] + histo[:-1]) * dx)
```

That works fine, but I want to do better than that.
Therefore I want to perform the integration with Romberg's method. To this purpose I want to use `scipy.integrate.romberg` (not a necessity, but I guess in Python it's the only way).

So I first make the `histo` a function, say something like

```
lambda z: function_histo(z)
```

and then I use the method

```
integrate.romb(histo_function, min, max)
```

where `min` and `max` are the extremes of integration.

My question is: how would I need to create this "function" `histo_function`?

Comment: Sounds like the function actually has to be a callable that takes an x-value as input and yields a y-value as output. I guess you need a function which can give you a smooth curve from the histogram, so probably some kind of interpolation function.

Comment: That said, I feel like you will become beholden to the errors of the interpolation function, so your integral will not be exact _anyway_. You might be better off computing the integral using only the data points you actually _know_. That way you can probably estimate the extent of error in your integral better.

Comment: What do you mean by "samples" at some positions of a continuous function?  Doesn't a function have a specific *value* at each position?

Comment: @PaulCornelius yes sorry that's maybe not the best English. I just mean to say that I do not have a callable function but just a list of representative values

Comment: @Praveen very good point. Then how would you suggest that I sould compute the integral? Perhaps some more refined way than just a trapezoidal rule

Comment: In that case perhaps you don't have a "histogram" at all but just a list of (x, y) values, where the y's are the function values for each x?

Comment: Good question. Honestly, I don't know what the best way is. If I did, I'd have posted an answer instead :-)

Comment: @PaulCornelius indeed

Comment: Then I would suggest that you have already solved the problem mathematically with the trapezoidal rule.  If you don't know what the function actually is, you have no valid way to interpolate between known points.  The only thing you can do is to integrate as best you can with the data points you've got.